FastAPI gunicorn concurrent process worker behaving strange
I have a sample fastAPI code as follows.I have noticed that the requests to my server are not handled properly by gunicorn workers. I have 8 workers available via gunicorn command. I tested with 6 requests at a time and noticed a pattern.As soon as 6 requests are made, the first request is immeidately processed and the remaining 5 are pooled together and as soon as the first request is completed, the 5 /pending requests received while processing the first one is started to execute together. Now any request coming at this time will be pooled/ waited until the 5 requests are processed and as soon as the 5 requests are processed, first request from the pooled request is procesed and as soon as the first is completed, rest are processed together. What can be the issue here? I am not understanding the reason for this strange behaviour.
gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app --bind unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock -w 10 -t 120
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    print("Start")
    time.sleep(20)
    print("Done")
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content="OK",media_type="application/json")

Logs are as follows:

INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:7777 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [5756] using WatchFiles
INFO:     Started server process [75304]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53432 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Start
Start
Start
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53432 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53433 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53461 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53462 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53464 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53518 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Start
Start
Start
Start
Start
Done
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53519 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53555 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53558 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53561 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53567 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53567 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Start
Start
Start
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53567 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53589 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53611 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53616 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53567 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Start
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53567 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Start
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53655 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53678 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53567 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53689 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Done
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53689 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Start
Start
Start
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53689 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53718 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53745 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53749 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53753 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53689 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Start
Start
Done
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53689 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

what can be the issue here?

This is normal behavior between synchronous python and gunicorn. I recommend using asynchronous sleep to simulate I/O bound operations. Here is my example and logs. I made several requests in a row.
Example:
import uuid
from asyncio import sleep

from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    _id = uuid.uuid4()
    print(f"Start{_id}")
    await sleep(10)
    print(f"Done {_id}")
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content="OK",media_type="application/json")

And logs
Startad6b768d-51fd-4a47-ba8e-e7ee426d913b
Start31c8ddb6-61e9-4af6-89a6-8cde8f335822
Start918c0102-d36e-43a2-9b59-6ab37b8f88f2
Start2ee69fac-e9cd-40b7-ae10-cffeaa1a731e
Start484a2f86-6474-4e4c-b6be-b748a427a1fe
Start8ef180d6-3e8b-44ac-8179-8fd47550e624
Done ad6b768d-51fd-4a47-ba8e-e7ee426d913b
Done 31c8ddb6-61e9-4af6-89a6-8cde8f335822
Done 918c0102-d36e-43a2-9b59-6ab37b8f88f2
Done 2ee69fac-e9cd-40b7-ae10-cffeaa1a731e
Done 484a2f86-6474-4e4c-b6be-b748a427a1fe
Done 8ef180d6-3e8b-44ac-8179-8fd47550e624

time.sleep(20) blocks the main thread, but await switch context to another request

Thanks. But I have blocking I/O operations in place of the sleep function. For e.g: Reading from AWS DynamoDB using boto3. For use case like this, how can I make sure the requests are being handled in a more efficient way?

The question is changed here. So, check this answer.
